# How to print a form in c#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, printing, teechart

I am using teecharts with C# and I want to print the graph that is generated to a pdf. Does anyone have any recommendations that are preferably free? This is a desktop application that uses forms.

Comment: is the graph generated to on aspx page

Comment: It is a form, I edited the question

Comment: No need of a 3rd party component as TeeChart has built-in functionality for generating PDF files from charts. See my reply below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use devloper express Charts. It will to export the data from chart to different types of files.

```
if (chartControl1.IsPrintingAvailable)
{
  // Exports to a PDF file.
  chartControl1.ExportToPdf("Output.pdf");
}
```

**[Refer: XtraCharts](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraCharts/CustomDocument2506)**

**[Create a Chart using the Wizard](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraCharts/CustomDocument5913)**

Comment: xtracharts are elegant but they are expensive.

Comment: No need of a 3rd party component as this user already has TeeChart and it has built-in functionality for generating PDF files from charts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible as TeeChart includes PDF export:

```
  tChart1.Export.Image.PDF.Save(fileName);
```

For further exporting options please have a look at tutorial 12. Tutorials can be found at TeeChart's program group.